# Serialize tasks with QueueBackgroundWorkItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Can I use HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(...) to serialize tasks? What I mean is that the tasks cannot overlap. A new task can only start once another one has finished. Is that possible with QueueBackgroundWorkItem or do I need to spin my own queue with only multiple producers (web requests) but one consumer.

Answer (score 0):

`QueueBackgroundWorkItem` adds tasks to the thread pool. It is very difficult to control the sequence of execution of tasks on the thread pool, but typically several tasks run simultaneously.

If your “tasks” are `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`s, then you can run them sequentially without blocking with:

```
var t = FirstTask();
t = t.ContinueWith( a => SecondTask() );
t = t.ContinueWith( a => ThirdTask() );
await t;
```

Comment: How would that look like within an web request? I mean where would I sequence the tasks within a Web API?

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32343453/edit) your question to include an example of the “Web API” you are using.

Comment: I don't think there is sensible way of serializing tasks using QueueBackgroundWorkItem. My solution was to create local app which takes in task requests and then serializes them using c#'s BlockingCollection with only one consumer.